# jQuery ,height() not applying exact value

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV. This div has a 6px padding.

I am running this jQuery on it:

```
$('.target').height(150);
```

But when I look at the HTML in chrome inspector, I am seeing it apply the following:

```
style="height: 162px;"
```

How do I get jQuery to apply 150px, and not and not 150px+padding?

Comment: Try setting it to `150-padding`

Comment: I am using this is various places, with different paddings. It wouldn't be feasible to subtract a static padding value.

Answer (score 0):

You're using some globally `box-sizing` set to `border-box`.

to ***"fix"?* your problem** set it to `content-box`

```
.target{
   box-sizing: content-box;
   padding: 6px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/as5ptvha/)**

Either way the element will always **visually** have a surface *height* of 162 (150 + 12px padding) but you'll now see the correctly applied `style="height:150"` - if that bothers you.

`box-sizing` is invented for the exact purpose that, we developers, don't have to go trough the nightmare of: 1. using padding in `%` 2. calculate widths and subtract padding size to create layouts.
Therefore we can set say 20px paddings to a `%`-sized element aand don't bother at all - If we've set say a width of `300px` it will not end up being `340`; or if an element has `width:50%; padding:20px;` we're assured an exact one can fit next to it.

So if some element **inherits** a `border-box` **box-sizing** jQuery is smart enough to compensate for paddings in order to get the exact visual result.

https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/

> Using box-sizing: border-box changes the CSS notion of the width of an element to include both the padding and the border dimensions, just the way you’d naturally measure it. jQuery versions before 1.8 were not fully trained in the ways of the border-box, but we’ve fixed this bug.

Inspecting the **[jQuery 3.2.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js) core code** you can find this of interest:

```
function getWidthOrHeight( elem, name, extra ) {

    // Start with computed style
    var valueIsBorderBox,
        styles = getStyles( elem ),
        val = curCSS( elem, name, styles ),
        isBorderBox = jQuery.css( elem, "boxSizing", false, styles ) === "border-box";

    // Computed unit is not pixels. Stop here and return.
    if ( rnumnonpx.test( val ) ) {
        return val;
    }

    // Check for style in case a browser which returns unreliable values
    // for getComputedStyle silently falls back to the reliable elem.style
    valueIsBorderBox = isBorderBox &&
        ( support.boxSizingReliable() || val === elem.style[ name ] );

    // Fall back to offsetWidth/Height when value is "auto"
    // This happens for inline elements with no explicit setting (gh-3571)
    if ( val === "auto" ) {
        val = elem[ "offset" + name[ 0 ].toUpperCase() + name.slice( 1 ) ];
    }

    // Normalize "", auto, and prepare for extra
    val = parseFloat( val ) || 0;

    // Use the active box-sizing model to add/subtract irrelevant styles
    return ( val +
        augmentWidthOrHeight(
            elem,
            name,
            extra || ( isBorderBox ? "border" : "content" ),
            valueIsBorderBox,
            styles
        )
    ) + "px";
}
```

and of course the `augmentWidthOrHeight` function (culprit or your `150` → `162`)

```
function augmentWidthOrHeight( elem, name, extra, isBorderBox, styles ) {
    var i,
        val = 0;

    // If we already have the right measurement, avoid augmentation
    if ( extra === ( isBorderBox ? "border" : "content" ) ) {
        i = 4;

    // Otherwise initialize for horizontal or vertical properties
    } else {
        i = name === "width" ? 1 : 0;
    }

    for ( ; i < 4; i += 2 ) {

        // Both box models exclude margin, so add it if we want it
        if ( extra === "margin" ) {
            val += jQuery.css( elem, extra + cssExpand[ i ], true, styles );
        }

        if ( isBorderBox ) {

            // border-box includes padding, so remove it if we want content
            if ( extra === "content" ) {
                val -= jQuery.css( elem, "padding" + cssExpand[ i ], true, styles );
            }

            // At this point, extra isn't border nor margin, so remove border
            if ( extra !== "margin" ) {
                val -= jQuery.css( elem, "border" + cssExpand[ i ] + "Width", true, styles );
            }
        } else {

            // At this point, extra isn't content, so add padding
            val += jQuery.css( elem, "padding" + cssExpand[ i ], true, styles );

            // At this point, extra isn't content nor padding, so add border
            if ( extra !== "padding" ) {
                val += jQuery.css( elem, "border" + cssExpand[ i ] + "Width", true, styles );
            }
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```